# Method does not have an implementation when loading assemblies into a new AssemblyLoadContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a simple app with plugins with each plugin loading into a separate AssemblyLoadContext, but when i try to call method GetExportedTypes() of plugin assembly i get **TypeLoadException 'Method 'M' in type 'T' from assembly 'A' does not have an implementation'**.
Method that does not have implementation comes from class that inherits from an common interface, interface in turn is in an assembly that is shared between app and plugin.
If i load all plugin assemblies with AssemblyLoadContext.Default everything works fine and there is no error.
The other fun fact is that error only happens when plugin refereces **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer**
The shared interface assembly is not present in plugin folder and is in a local nuget source, so ther is no version mismatch

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this problem too. In my case, the plugin dll was referencing another dll that was used by both Default AssemblyLoadContext and my plugin AssemblyLoadContext. Once I have explicitly set in the csproj of my plugin the

```
<Private>true</Private>
<ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
```

for both the shared assemblies, everything worked like a charm.

Hope it helps you too.

Otherwise, a more generic solution might be to go into your plugin's custom AssemblyLoadContext and write the Load method as follows

```
protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
    {
        // This will fallback to loading the assembly from default context.
        if (AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Assemblies.Any(a=> a.FullName == assemblyName.FullName))
            return null;

        string assemblyPath = _resolver.ResolveAssemblyToPath(assemblyName);
        if (assemblyPath != null)
        {
            return LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyPath);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just seen an error similar to this, though my plugins are being loaded by way of the *McMaster.NETCore.Plugins* package.

In my case the problem was caused by a subtle mismatch in dependency versioning.

My host project had a dependency on *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer* version 3.1.7 whereas my plugin had a reference to version 3.1.8. Aligning the plugin version with the host version fixed the problem.

Comment: How would this solve anything if plugin dependencies should load their own version in their own `AssemblyLoadContext`?